# How to exclude unwanted matches from randomly matched strings

Tags: c#, arrays

For example I have such a code.

```
string[] person = new string[] { "Son", "Father", "Grandpa" };
string[] age = new string[] { "Young", "In his 40-s", "Old" };

string[] unwanted = new string { "Old Son", "Young GrandPa" };

Random X = new Random();
string Who = person[i.Next(0, person.Length)];
string HowOld = age[i.Next(0, age.Length)];
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Who, HowOld);
```

I want to get all random matches BUT THEN exclude two variants from the array "unwanted"). (surely it's just an example, there can be many more arrays and possible bad matches).

What is the good way to do it? The keypoint that I wanna keep the possibility to get ALL results anyway. So I wanna have option to exclude stuff AFTER generation, but not making it impossible to generate "old son".

Comment: Why not just filter out all unwanted data before querying it by random index?

Comment: `if(Who == "Grandpa"  HowOld == "Young"){/*select different values*/}`

Comment: Sounds like what you really want to do is split your array of ages up into young/old ages and store a young/old identifier against each person type.

Comment: Well, I'd like to have an option to get all the results anyway. But to have method that will delete some matches after they are generated. So that I have two options - one totally chaotic and one - chaotic but with predefined exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

First, define a class that holds both values from the arrays:

```
class PersonWithAge
{
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Next, use LINQ to generate all possible combinations of Person and Age:

```
// Create cross product
var results = (from x in person
               from y in age
               select new PersonWithAge{Person=x, Age=y}).ToList();
```

Now (if desired) remove the exceptions:

```
results.RemoveAll(n => n.Person == "Son" && n.Age == "Old"
                    || n.Person == "Grandpa" && n.Age == "Young");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent some combination I belief you could have 'rules' of pairs/groups that cannot be matched together like for instance an `string[][] blocked` or `int[][] blocked` when, if accessing `blocked[i][j]`, `i` is the current word and the array `blocked[i]` are the indexes of the words (or the words themselves) it cannot be matched with (all of this assuming you might have more than 1 word you  potentially don't want to match to the current one, in case of just one a simple array will suffice), Then you just have to make sure the random value you use is not one of those 'forbidden'. Hope this helps